# Enable IPhone Intellisense without Pressing Escape Key

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there anyway to just turn on the intellisense support in XCode without having to press the escape key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you enter this in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode XCCodeSenseAutoSuggestionStyle List
```

and restart Xcode, you get the popup menu with the code completion suggestions right away. I vastly prefer this to Xcode's default setting.